# Escape the square brackets and quotation marks or fetch this array without the quotes and brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a class `my_class.rb` which has a public method `get_names`

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base

  ##.....##

  def get_names
     self.students.collect {|x| x.name}
  end
end
```

on the view I am calling the method to fill a form input field like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @movie do |f| %> 
   ...

    <%= f.input :get_names %> 
<% end %>
```

the values that fill the input field looks like this:

```
["William", "Alexis", "John", "Richard"]
```

but i would like them to look like this:

```
 William, Alexis, John, Richard
```

What changes can i make to `get_names` method or how can i escape the brackets and quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `join` method on your array :

`["William", "Alexis", "John", "Richard"].join(", ")`

So here you can just do :

`self.students.collect {|x| x.name}.join(", ")`

but your method will then return a string and not an array.